Does $M_{2,3}(\mathbb{R})$ define a vector space adequately?
I was reading my instructor's notes on vector spaces. I came across the following:

Example 9.2.2 Let $M_{2,3}(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of all $2\times3$ matrices over $\mathbb R$. Show that $M_{2,3}(\mathbb{R})$
is a real vector space under standard matrix addition and scalar
multiplication. $\tag{#}$

My thoughts
$$\mathbb R^3\  \text{is a vector space over}\  \mathbb R\tag{1}$$
$(1)$ is an adequate definition of a vector space. It mentions three important things:

The set to which the entries of the vectors belong. So, say $\textbf{u}=$ $\begin{bmatrix}x_{11} \\
    x_{21}  \\
    x_{31} \end{bmatrix}$ is an element of $\mathbb R^3$. From $(1)$ - specifically from the expression $\mathbb{R^3}$ - we can understand that $x_{11}, x_{21}, x_{31}\in \mathbb{R}$.
The dimension of the vector space: $3$.
The field $\mathbb F$ associated with the vector space: $\mathbb R$.

My question
In $\text{(#)}$, however, the first point is not mentioned. So, is $M_{2,3}(\mathbb{R})$ an adequate description of a vector space?

In (#) it says to show that something is a real vector space. This is a synonym for a vector space over $\mathbb R$. So the field of scalars is given (what you call tag A).

And it is not true that vectors have entries.

I don't understand your question at all.  You seem to be claiming that you need to know what a typical element of a purported vector space "looks like".  While we might argue about that, it seems like it has been pretty clearly stated in the problem.  A typical element is a $2\times 3$ matrix.  I am not sure that I understand where the confusion is.

Your Thought 2, that the description of a vector space should mention its dimension, is not normally held.

The quoted example says

Show that $M_{2,3}(\mathbb R)$ is a real vector space under standard matrix addition and scalar multiplication.

All the necessary information is in the statement, in particular, the field of scalars we deduce from "real vector space", that is the field of scalars is $\mathbb R$.
